# Snackbar.setCallBack is deprecated?

Tags: android

I want to override the `onDismissed` of my `Snackbar` but I am getting a warning that `Snackbar.setCallback` is deprecated.  Is there a different way to Override `onDismissed`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry I found it. Use addCallback instead of setCallback. I'm seeing this pattern in many deprecated "set" methods.

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation notice indicates that you need to use the `addCallback` method instead.

See the [documentation here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#setCallback%28android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.Callback%29)